# Can the gluing lemma also hold for smooth maps that agree on closed sets?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

In topology, the Gluing Lemma states that two continuous functions $f:A\rightarrow X$ and $g:B\rightarrow X$ defined on closed subsets $A$ and $B$ will define a continuous function on the union $A\cup B$, provided that $f$ and $g$ agree on the intersection $A\cap B$. I am curious about what happens if we add smoothness everywhere. Consider the following statement:

> If $A$ and $B$ are closed smooth submanifolds, with $f:A\rightarrow N$ and $g:B\rightarrow N$ smooth maps such that $f|_{A\cap B} = g|_{A\cap B}$, then $h:A\cup B\rightarrow N$ defined by $$h(x) = \begin{cases} f(x) & \text{if } x\in A \\ g(x) & \text{if } x\in B \end{cases}$$ is a smooth map.

Obviously this is not true in general, and the notion of a piecewise smooth curve is a fine counterexample. That being said, are there any non-trivial circumstances under which this statement might hold? e.g. what about if I add in the extra condition that $A$ and $B$ are codim-$0$ and $Int(A) \cap Int(B)$ is non-empty?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your counterexample. Can you give an example?

Comment: Closed submanifold with or without boundary?  Without boundary the statement is vacuous, with boundary it fails with e.g. $A=[0,2]\cup[3,4]$, $B=[1,3]$ at the point $3$ --- you want every component of $A\cap B$ to have nonempty interior.

Comment: @agent_cracker103 Consider maps with domains [-1,0] and [0,1], mapped into $\mathbb{R}^2$. Send the first interval to the x-axis, i.e. $x\mapsto (x,0)$, and send the second interval to the y-axis, i.e. $y\mapsto (0,y)$. These two maps are smooth functions, and they agree on $0$ (their intersection), but the composite curve is not smooth at $0$.

Comment: I see. For smoothness it's probably enough to demand that all the limits in $A$ of the derivatives on the boundry of $A\cap{B}$ agree with all the limits in $B$ of the derivatives on the boundry of $A\cap{B}$. 
For example in your example it fails because $(1,0)\neq(0,1)$

Comment: Let me check if a got the question: the following [function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Piecewise%5B%7B%7Be%5E%28-1%2Fx%5E2%29%2C+x+%3C+0%7D%2C+%7B0%2C+0%3C%3Dx+%3C%3D+2%7D%2C+%7Be%5E%28-1%2F%28x-2%29%5E2%29%2C+x%3E2%7D%7D%5D&lang=es): $$ f(x)=\begin{cases} \exp\left(-\dfrac{1}{x^2}\right),\quad x<0,\\ 0,\quad 0\leq x\leq 2,\\  \exp\left(-\dfrac{1}{(x-2)^2}\right),\quad x>2 \end{cases}$$ is going to be an example or a counter-example?

Comment: @Joako your function is a non-example, since two of the three domains are open subsets. I am asking about the well-known situation of the [gluing lemma/pasting lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma), but instead just replace "continuous" with "smooth". There are obvious counterexamples, but it is not clear what extra conditions are needed in order to get a positive answer.

Comment: @user10354138 with boundaries. I agree that making every connected component have non-empty interior would probably work. Can you elaborate on this a bit?

Comment: *Hint*: Prove that every point of $(A\cup B)^\circ$ is either in $A^\circ$ or $B^\circ$ if every component of $A\cap B$ has nonempty interior.